# MVC Default root without area

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-areas

I am trying to use Areas in MVC. If login is successfull, you are being redirected to `Index` of `HomeController` in `Admin` Area. What I want to do is to redirect you to `Index` of `HomeController` of the default area, however when I logout, I stay in `Admin` area. How to redirect back out of Admin area?

**Login inside nav**

```
     <ul class="nav masthead-nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Home")">Domů</a></li>
          <li><a href="@Url.Action("About", "Home")">O nás</a></li>
          <li><a href="@Url.Action("Index", "Login", new {area = "Admin" })">Vypis lyží/snowboardů</a></li>
     </ul>
```

**Login Controller Actions Signup/Signout**

```
public ActionResult SignIn(string login, string password)
        {
            if (Membership.ValidateUser(login, password))
            {
                FormsAuthentication.SetAuthCookie(login, false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            TempData["error"] = "Login nebo heslo není správné";
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Login");
        }

        public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Session.Clear();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
```

**Route Config**

```
 public class RouteConfig
    {
        public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
        {
            routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

            routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Default",
                url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                namespaces: new [] { "pujcovna_lyze.Controllers" }
            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hey, good luck on your project! Did you have a specific question for us or...?

Comment: @GrumpyCrouton what do you mean? I thought It was clear from the text, however I have added mine question.

Answer (score 2):

I have solved the issue by adding `new { area = "" }` parameter in the `Logout()` action.

The Action now looks like this:

```
public ActionResult Logout()
        {
            FormsAuthentication.SignOut();
            Session.Clear();

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home", new { area = "" });
        }
```